# Unable to view output of script in bl.ocks.org

Tags: javascript, html, csv, d3.js

I have been trying to figure out why my code is unable to be viewed in bl.ocks.org. I'd really like to see it up somewhere.

My code is for a bar chart that can handle changes in records and values created from a .csv file.

I have made sure that my code is working outside of this loading it from a local server from it's folder that contains the .html file and the .csv file.

I've ensured that it's not the browser cache either.

It can be found here: http://bl.ocks.org/parnelandr/7887491

Any help would be appreciated. I'm sure I've just missed something along the way.

Comment: It looks like you haven't included D3 in that gist.

Comment: Yup, adding `<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>` works: http://bl.ocks.org/musically-ut/7892503

Comment: Of course! Much appreciated. Makes total sense!

Comment: I'll add that as an answer for reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `d3.js` script you're referencing in your gist has a local path, i.e. it would need to be part of the gist as well, which it isn't. It should work fine if you either add `d3.js` or (preferably) reference the global URL to it instead.